# animateWithDuration Completion block fires over and over again

Tags: ios, animation, completionhandler, animatewithduration

I've got a little animation going, and when that animation ends I want the App to automatically push the next `ViewController` on. Well that `ViewController` gets pushed on like 8 times in a row! Its pretty crazy.

here's the code:

```
     if CGRectIntersectsRect(whichButton.frame, targetZoneImgView.frame) {
        panGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = true
        let buttonSnapX = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 2.0 - 35.0
        let buttonSnapY = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 122.0

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.75, delay: 0.0, 
                usingSpringWithDamping: 0.1, 
                 initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, 
                               options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, 
                            animations: {
                                 myButton.frame.origin.x = buttonSnapX
                                 myButton.frame.origin.y = buttonSnapY
                            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
                                  print("Animation done!")
                                  let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
                                  let coursesScreen = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("coursesScreen") as! CoursesVC                  
                                  self.navigationController!.pushViewController(coursesScreen, animated: true)
                               }
                           )
```

That `print("Animation done!")` statement also fires like 8-9 times in a row, so its really got nothing to do with the fact that I'm pushing a ViewController. I took out the `ViewController` code - and its still happening.

Basically, *anything* I put in `completion` is firing a whole bunch of times in a row.

What in the world is going on?

Comment: I've never personally run into that before, but see if it stops if you don't use a spring animation. (Just a classic `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:`) If that fixes it, then I bet apple's doing something very silly in their spring animations!

Answer (score 0):

You may enter completion block with `false` value of `finished` variable. Just add a basic check:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.75, delay: 0.0, 
                usingSpringWithDamping: 0.1, 
                 initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, 
                               options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, 
                            animations: {
                                 myButton.frame.origin.x = buttonSnapX
                                 myButton.frame.origin.y = buttonSnapY
                            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
                                 if finished {
                                    print("Animation done!")
                                    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
                                    let coursesScreen = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("coursesScreen") as! CoursesVC                  
                                    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(coursesScreen, animated: true)
                                 } else {
                                    print("Animating...")
                                 }
                            }
                          )
```

Comment: I tried the `if finished` bit before posting the question - it didn't work. But since you suggested it, I went on some more exploration... I think problem has more to do with the fact that a dragging gesture triggers this whole thing. When I drag one object into another - that's when this animation kicks in. So its `if CGRectIntersectsRect`. Maybe original dragging gesture isn't getting cancelled, so it causes the thing to get triggered over and over again.  I tried cancelling the touch event - no luck. But maybe you have some other ideas given you now know its all tied to a gesture?

Comment: See edited code in the original question. I added the `if CGRectIntersectsRect` bit before the whole thing.